# FunctionDomain - Meaning of "True" in output and documentation

Tags: functions, regions

Can someone tell me the meaning of `True` in output when I use `FunctionDomain` please? I guess that the meaning of `True` is: the whole domain (R in the example below).
Moreover I'd like to read documentation where I can find an explanation.

```
FunctionDomain[x, {x}]
(* Out: True *)
```

Thank you for your willingness.

Answer (score 3):

`FunctionDomain` yields a predicate that's `True` when the variable is in the domain, so if the domain is unrestricted, the result is simply `True`.

Comment: Hello @JohnDoty, is there any documentation related to it?

Comment: Just the stuff in the Documentation Center.

Comment: The default domain is `Reals` so `True` means that `Element[x, Reals]` evaluates to `True`